# Creating a drip campaign with ExactTarget (Marketing Cloud)

Tags: marketing-cloud

I'm trying to set up an email series. I'm new to this, so apologies if I sound basic. Here's what's going on:

I am using FormStack to build a form. I linked the formstack form to a list in Marketing Cloud. When I enter my email address into the form, I'm added to the list (this is a win!).

I now want to set up an email series to the newly added email addresses on the list. What is the best way to go about doing this?

I looked at "simple automated emails" but it's asking for a "subscriber date attribute" and I don't have one).

I went to Automation Studio but that is very confusing/complicated and I don't see the option to use a list (or a data extension for that matter).

Based on googling, "triggered emails" doesn't sound too promising either.

Please help?

thanks

jeff

Answer (score 1):

According to your scenario - if you're able to get the list populated from **FormStack** then there is a simple solution to this.

As soon as the form is populated the records in the list will receive an email.

**Here is the process:**

- Setup a list in salesforce marketing cloud which will link to FormStack. Now you will assign a Welcome Email (it can be any email) option to your List.
- Your email has to be setup in classic content builder first. Then select your email in the list creation process.
- Once it is all setup you will be able to trigger your welcome email to the subscribers in the list using Formstack.

Note: You can only setup welcome email option during the creation of the list. This feature may not be enabled in your account. For more information, contact your account representative.

More information [here](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/resources/solution_guides/welcome_email/assign_a_welcome_email_to_a_list/).

[image: Here is the image reference.]

Comment: This is great. Thank you. I'm hoping to speak with customer support, as we will need a series of emails (drip campaign) over the course of 7 days. I'm thinking that the "Welcome email" will be a one time email. thanks for the reply!

Comment: You can setup multiple list for series of emails. If this solution helped you, could you please accept my answer. Thanks

Comment: I'm actually looking to create a series of emails from 1 list. Users fill out a form, are added to a list and then a series of emails begins. day 1 = 1 email, day 2 = next email and so on.

Comment: If the list that is being populated is a sendable list, you should be able to use automation studio, or Journey builder to create a campaign with however many emails you want to send.

Comment: @JeffreyKlein Are you wishing to trigger the email as soon as the form is submitted?

Answer (score 0):

Journey Builder fits best as per your requirement. Journey builder has feature to send an email after waiting for certain period of time (min, hour, day etc)